# get 8 digit after comma in python

Tags: python

I wouldlike to get 8 digit after comma but I tried everything, no one solution actually resolve my problem:

```
tab_freq=(result[1]/1e6)
value_freq=str(tab_freq)[1:-1]
print value_freq
```

I tried this :

```
 value_freq2=format(value_freq,".8f")
```

and I get always the same error :

```
Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`".8f"` will work on numbers, not strings.

Try converting it to a float first:

```
value_freq2=format(float(value_freq),".8f")
```

---

**Edit:**

In response to your comments below, you first need to split all the values in value_freq2 and apply the format to each one, then rejoin them.

```
value_freq = "100. 100.98 105.344444 104."
value_list = [format(float(v), ".8f") for v in value_freq.split()]
value_freq2 = "\n".join(value_list)
```

Comment: I tried but I have another error :`invalid literal for float():` 99.99999949 100.    100.254..... this function do not add 8 zero after comma ?

Comment: It looks like you're passing a list of values.  You'll need to split it up with `str.split()` first.

Comment: With my script I send data by bluetooth with that : client_sock.send('\n'.join(value_freq2.split())) to ordonate my list of values when some value don't have the same lenght like : 105.and 104.99999949 for example. I want the same lenght like 105.00000000

Comment: Okay, makes sense.  You need to apply the format for each value in value_freq2.split() and then join that list. I'll edit the solution to address this.

Comment: so if I understand, `client_sock.send('\n'.join(format(value_freq2.split(), ".8f"))` ?